# What is the best practice to set the size of a <table>?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to learn what is the best practice to set a table size -the width- so that the contents in the cells will not go out of the table (especially horizontally) but they will be forced to stay in the cells.

Do I need to set width, height on the `<table>` element level or I should do it both for `<tr>` and `<td>` elements?

For example, this table:

```
<table>
        <tr >
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                Mr.Tuber
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr >
            <td>
                Surname
            </td>
            <td>
                Tupova
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the cell will never go outside the tables as long as you're putting text in the cells.

A good way to build a table like this is to set the overall size of the table, as well as the widths of the columns, using CSS. Let the table expand vertically to accommodate the content automatically.

```
<table class="table1">
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">
                Name
            </td>
            <td class="col2">
                Mr.Tuber
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                Surname
            </td>
            <td>
                Tupova
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.table1 {
     width:500px
}

table1 .col1 {
     width:200px
}
```

You don't need to specifically set col2, since it will take whatever space if left over. You may wish to also use `TH` instead of `TD` for the title cells so you can style those differently than the content cells.

```
.table1 th { ... }
```